# Await for set useState to finish in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I've been trying for a while now to force `useState` setter to behave in synchronous manner or to await for a state change before re-rendering. My simplified code:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const SelectedFileContent = () => {
  const selectedFile = useSelector(state => state.fileSelected);
  const [fileContent, setFileContent] = useState(null);
  
  const loadFileContent = async (name) => {
    const f = await fetch(`static/${name}`).then(data => data.json());
    console.log('In loadFileContent: ', fileContent)
    return f;
  }
  
  const fetchFileContent = async () => {
    await loadFileContent(selectedFile).then(data => setFileContent(data))
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFileContent();
    console.log('In useEffect: ', fileContent)
  }, [selectedFile])

    return (
      <div>Selected file content: {fileContent}</div>
    )
}
```

I've read multiple SO questions and answers but none of that worked for me. What my code does: first, it reads `selectedFile` name from redux state. When this value changes, useEffect hook is being called (because of `selectedFile` in dependency array). In useEffect, `loadFileContent` function is being called, which in turn, loads file content and stores it in the `fileContent` variable.

My issue is that since `useState` setter is asynchronous and cannot be awaited, new value is being set too late and I can see with console logs in browser console that it's one state behind all the time - if for example, file `1.json` with content `{"filename": "1.json"}` is being loaded, and then file `2.json` - those console logs are printing `{"filename": "1.json"}` instead of `{"filename": "2.json"}`, as I'd like to. What I would like to achieve is that on any re-render upon `selectedFile` changes, correct file content will be stored in `fileContent` const, without causing re-render when finished (This is just my assumption it happens though, not sure yet how to count it). But when I've added `{console.log(fileContent)}` in the return statement, it logged file content correctly.

I've tried following things:

- in `fetchFileContent`, instead of passing loaded data directly to the `setFileContent`, split it in two lines
- added loading/setLoading helper state - `setLoading(true)` before `fetchFileContent` and then `setLoading(false)` plus conditional rendering in the return statement (`{fileContent && !loading ? ... : ...}`)

Also, when I've added additional `useEffect` hook, it logged file content properly:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(fileContent);
  }, [fileContent])
```

Comment: "...or to await for a state change before re-rendering..." This is how React works. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: "I've been trying for a while now to force useState setter to behave in synchronous manner" This sounds like you are fighting against React. Why do you need the setter to behave synchronously?

Comment: `What I would like to achieve is that on any re-render upon selectedFile changes, correct file content will be stored in fileContent` It will `without causing re-render when finished` It can not __not__ rerender.

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around what you're trying to achieve with this. Do you, by any chance, want to have the latest `fileContent` in your `useEffect` hook? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong here, but my understanding is, that after `useState` setter will resolve, then page will re-render. I would like to "await" for this change to finish,  until `fileContent` will have the latest data.  So basically you're right @Kapobajza, I'd like to have this state up-to-date in `useEffect`.

Comment: You can't. Either write another `useEffect` using `fileContent` as dependency or just do what you want to do in `then`. Or await and get the result out.